# Dejar columnas vacías en vista SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando crear una vista a partir de dos tablas. Hasta aquí no hay ningún problema.

En el ejemplo tenemos unas cartas de restaurantes y unas categorías de productos relacionadas con las cartas anteriores, necesito que en la misma vista aparezcan todas las cartas y las categorías que existen, y si una de las cartas no tiene una categoría relacionada, entonces convertir las columnas a vacías.

**El problema** viene cuando una de las cartas no está relacionada con ninguna categoría, entonces no se dibuja la fila.

Esta es la query:

```
CREATE VIEW cartas_y_categorias AS 
SELECT 
  ws_cartas.id AS carta_id, 
  ws_cartas.nombre AS carta_nombre, 
  ws_cartas.descripcion AS carta_descripcion, 
  ws_cartas.horario AS carta_horario, 
  ws_categorias.id AS categoria_id, 
  ws_categorias.nombre AS categoria_nombre, 
  ws_categorias.descripcion AS categoria_descripcion 
FROM 
  (
    ws_categorias 
    join ws_cartas on(
      (
        ws_categorias.carta_id = ws_cartas.id
      )
    )
  );
```

Esta es la vista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la tabla de las cartas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea?, Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Herramienta sugerida para mejorar la presentación de código: https://codebeautify.org/sqlformatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haces la consulta con un JOIN directo entre las tablas de Categorías y la tabla de Cartas, por lo que sólo obtendrás resultados de aquellos registros donde haya combinación de las dos cosas.
Deberías hacer una consulta de Cartas (que es la tabla principal y de la que quieres todos sus datos en esta vista) con un LEFT JOIN de Categorías, para que aparezcan todas las cartas, y las categorías en caso de que existan para cada carta.
Sería algo así:

```
CREATE VIEW cartas_y_categorias AS 
SELECT 
  ws_cartas.id AS carta_id, 
  ws_cartas.nombre AS carta_nombre, 
  ws_cartas.descripcion AS carta_descripcion, 
  ws_cartas.horario AS carta_horario, 
  ws_categorias.id AS categoria_id, 
  ws_categorias.nombre AS categoria_nombre, 
  ws_categorias.descripcion AS categoria_descripcion 
FROM 
  (
     ws_cartas 
     LEFT JOIN ws_categorias ON(
        (
          ws_categorias.carta_id = ws_cartas.id
        )
     )
  );
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Está perfecto, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Otra cosa habitual que había olvidado... Si haces esa consulta y una carta tiene más de una categoría, aparecerá repetida. Una solución si sólo te interesa ver por ejemplo el nombre de las categorías de una carta (si tiene), sería cambiar las tres últimas columnas de la consulta por `GROUP_CONCAT(ws_categorias.nombre) AS catgorias_carta` y un `GROUP BY ws_cartas.id` al final de la consulta.